# npm install --force is failing

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm-install

Getting below error
I am trying to build reacts app using NPM install Cmdr. and unable to build that because of
following err.

Getting below error
I am trying to build reacts app using NPM install Cmdr. and unable to build that because of
following err.

```
"node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: \\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [`enter code here`
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:323:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a problem with `node-sass`.
Node-sass is deprecated. The best course of remediation would probably be to update your dependency to use [dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass/).

Usually when troubleshooting node-sass rebuild problems that fail in gyp, I suggest you make sure your machine has a `c++ build tools` and `python` in the system path (windows). I haven't trouble shot this in a while, ut python may need to be version 2.7 too.

EDIT: I believe the updated package, dart-sass, removed these build dependencies.

Comment: Hi I tried with python 2.7 version also but no luck